Springboot POST API is returning 200 but no JSON
I am a little confused as to why my Spring service is not returning any content. I tried mvn clean install and I also see that the response POJO at the return statement line has actual data when I hit the breakpoint in debugger mode/print to console. Does anyone know what could be the cause?
My @RestController
    @Override
    public MyServiceResponse getDesiredData(MyRequest myRequest)
            throws IOException {
        var resp = new MyServiceResponse();
        var req = new ServiceRequest<MyRequest>();

        req.setPayload(myRequest);

        // this update the pass by reference resp object
        myRequestProcessor.process(req, resp);

        return resp; //at this breakpoint I see data in the debugging console
    }

POJO:
@SuperBuilder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyServiceResponse {
    SessionInfo sessionInfo;
}

@SuperBuilder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SessionInfo {
    Parameters parameters;
}

@SuperBuilder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Parameters {
    @JsonProperty("zip")
    String zip;

    @JsonProperty("city")
    String city;

    @JsonProperty("state")
    String state;

    @JsonProperty("storeNum")
    Integer storeNum;

    @JsonProperty("startHrs")
    String startHrs;

    @JsonProperty("endHrs")
    String endHrs;
}


It turns out that in my specific case there is another class in the service package that implements the following:
@Pointcut(value = "execution(public * *(..))")
public void publicMethod() {
}

/**
 * @see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-combining
 */
@Pointcut(value = "within(com.example.api.service.MyServiceControllerImpl)")
public void forServiceClass() {
}

@Around("publicMethod() && forServiceClass()")
public Object processorLogging(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable { ... }

Due to this, the processorLogging is called before and after the API method is called in ControllerImpl. Inside this method the logic did not support a new POJO as the response object so I needed to add that support. Since this is implied behavior, I would verify that there are no additional logic executed past the return of the response in the controller method.

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/API")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @PostMapping("/getData")
    public ResponseEntity<MyServiceResponse> getData(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) {
        MyServiceResponse response = myService.getDesiredData(myRequest);

        if (response == null || response.getSessionInfo() == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build(); // Returns 204 No Content if response is null
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(response); // Returns 200 OK with JSON response
    }
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
